# Error: exit status 1 stray '#' in program

Tags: programming

I got this error:

```
exit status 1 stray '#' in program
```

How can I remove this error..?

```
int keys = {1,2,3,A,4,5,6,B,7,8,9,C,*,0,#,D};
```

Comment: you should use char literals instead of numbers, operators, identifiers and macros.
just place every single list entry in single quotes like this `{'1', ...'#', 'D'}`

Comment: only some of the elements in `keys` are integers ... you need to rethink what you are doing

Comment: If s/he quotes every one that will be OK. A single quoted character can be stored in an int.

Comment: "How can I remove this error?" Well, just delete your code from the beginning to the end and this will certainly "remove the error". Done. Now, please, make an effort to ask questions that at least makes some basic sense. Yours currently doesn't make any. Until you tell us what you were trying to do and what is that `#` doing there, there's no way to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

There are several -more or less severe- issues in your one line of code

```
const char keys[] = {'1','2','3','A'
                    ,'4','5','6','B'
                    ,'7','8','9','C'
                    ,'*','0','#','D' };
```

( Find the differences :) )

Depending on your usage, you eventually even need a 2-dimensional array

```
const char keys[4][4] =  ...
```